# How to get past a package error and a can not access error?

Tags: java, oop, package, extends

I compile my program and keep getting this error. The programs testW and Tractor are under the file named testtractor. In the Tractor program, I use package testtractor.java; at the beginning. In the testW program, I use import testtractor.java; at the beginning. Please Help !

testW.java:1: error: package testtractor does not exist
import testtractor.java;
                  ^
testW.java:3: error: cannot access Tractor
public class testW extends Tractor

```
 import testtractor.java;

 public class testTractor extends Tractor 
{
  private String name;
   private int VehicleID; 
   private int RentalRate;
   private int RentalDays;

 public String setName(String name) 
  {
    this.name = name;
  }
```

Comment: What did you name the package that contains the Tractor class? That is what you need to import.

Comment: Do you have a folder called testtractor that contains a file called Tractor.java? Or do you have a file called testtractor.java?

Comment: I have a folder called testtractor that contains a file called Tractor.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you import a class, and the way to do it would be

```
import pack.ag.e.ClassName;
```

So in your example if say the `Tractor` class is under `farm` package, you need to do this in you `testTractor` class.

```
import farm.Tractor;
```

Also java has certain naming conventions.
Class names should start with Caps letter, see this old page for conventions
Quote -

> Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of
>   each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple
>   and descriptive. Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations
>   (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form,
>   such as URL or HTML).

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 0):

Your import line is wrong - don't put .java on the end unless there is a class called `java` in the `testtractor` package.

You probably meant:

```
import testtractor.Tractor;
```

However, the error you show indicates that there is no package called testtractor.

Comment: Yeah that's a problem I will have to figure out on my own but Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You need to put full path of Tractor class as part of import statement:
So, if package is testtractor then you need to put:

```
import testtractor.Tractor;
```

Additionally you need to add package before import. So if your package is abc:

```
package abc;
```